# iOS 5 SDK issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I have a working application on iOS 4.
I have migrated to SDK 5, and now, on simulator and on devices the application just freeze.
There is no error or crash, just UI totaly freeze.
That occur only on the following case.
I have table view with FetshResultController that have list of object (Managed Objects).
Click on one of the list pushViewController with details.
For each list controller update i call tableView reloadData for the details view.

on iOS 4 there is no problem, but on iOS 5 after some time (can be minute or even few seconds) the entire UI freeze without any error. I need to forcly close the reopen the application.

Why is that issue on iOS 5 ? What can i do ?

(Compiling on iOS 4 is enabled to run on iOS 5, but i try to compile on iOS 5, so i will be able to debug it. iOS 4 SDK cannot "see" iOS 5)

Comment: just try using Instruments with NSZombies enabled ., that will figure out where the problem occurs.,

Comment: OK. Found it. But there is no Exception or memory issues. The UI just totally freeze. I have also added log messages regarding WebService calls that while the UI Freeze i can see that are still working. It seems that something with iOS 5, since i do not have that on iOS4

Comment: Well, THe UI was freezed, and nothing on NSZombies... Not even break point or somthing. like application keeps running, but no UI is working.